# Wrong image is shown in interface image in WatchKit

Tags: swift, watchkit

I'm seeing a bug in WatchKit where it shows a wrong image when assigned by name programmatically or from the storyboard. Am I doing anything wrong here?

### How to reproduce

1. Add images to the WatchKit app with names `image_1.png` and `image_10.png`.
2. Set the first image to the interface image: `image.setImageNamed("image_1")`

### Expected behaviour

First image `image_1.png` is shown.

### Actual behaviour

Second image `image_10.png` is shown.

### Tested in Xcode

- Version 6.2 (6C131e)
- Version 6.3 (6D532l)

### Demo

https://github.com/evgenyneu/watch-image-glitch-demo

### Update

This bug has been submitted to Apple Bug Reporter. Apple confirmed that this is a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely file a `Serious Bug` [radar](http://bugreport.apple.com). I pulled down your sample project (great work by the way) and ran it. I'm certainly seeing the same behavior on Xcode 6.2 (6C131e).

I also moved the images into the xcassets bundle which didn't have any affect on the issue. The only thing that I noticed is that renaming the `image_10` to `image_11`, `image_12` or `image_100` did fix the problem. It appears that only `image_10` is the culprit.

Comment: Thanks, submitted to Apple's bug reporter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show just one image, you can still use startAnimating with a range that starts at your image and has a length of 1 (duration is 0 in this case). It works fine as a workaround until the bug is fixed.